# Block certain country using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, block

Is there a simple and reliable way to block certain countries using .htaccess?

Simple means no IP range block lists - they need to be updated once in a while and can be quite long.

I understand, that it wouldn't apply to proxies.

Comment: @michaelb958 : Because I want to block a certain country using .htaccess

Comment: Nice circular answer. *Why?* Is it to filter out all the spammers? Is it to comply with some misguided law? Is it something else?

Comment: @michaelb958 : It's for russian spam blocking.

Comment: In that case, just understand that any legitimate users in Russia *will* be inconvenienced by a blanket block.

Comment: That's logical, but it doesn't matter - the page I want to use it on doesn't offer services outsite Europe.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest is probably using the [GeoIP Apache module](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/legacy/mod_geoip2). After installing and configuring you just need to do something like this in your htaccess file:

```
GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPDBFile /path/to/GeoIP.dat

SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE CN BlockCountry
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE RU BlockCountry
# ... place more countries here

Deny from env=BlockCountry
```

Comment: This looks promising, I will try it and let you know.